# Defining several variables at once (copy-paste-execute in shell)

Tags: shell-script, variable, syntax

I have a list of variables I copy-paste one by one from a file to my shell and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> to execute. For example:

```
var1="myvar1"
var2="myvar2"
```

Because in practice there are more variables, instead copy-pasting them and execute them one by one I desire to do all in one operation to save time.
I tried copy-pasting:

```
(
var1="myvar1"
var2="myvar2"
)
```

`echo $var1` outputs an empty line instead date in relevant format.

How could I execute a few variables in one operation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't have copy them one by one, you can paste all the lines together and newlines will work as Enter.

The reason that

```
(
var1="myvar1"
var2="myvar2"
)
```

doesn't work is that because it's executed in a subshell. It would work if you printed contents of the variable before the final
`)`:

```
(
var1="myvar1"
var2="myvar2"
echo $var2
)
```

It's explained in `Commpound Commands` section in `man bash`:

> Compound Commands
>
> A compound command is one of the following.  In most cases a list in a
>   command's description may be sepa- rated from the rest of the command
>   by one or more newlines, and may be followed by a newline in place of
>   a semicolon.
>
> (list) list is executed in a subshell environment  (see  COMMAND 
>   EXECUTION  ENVIRONMENT  below).   Variable   assignments  and  builtin
>   commands that affect the shell's environment do not remain in effect
>   after   the command completes.  The return status is the exit status
>   of list.

Later on it also says:

> { list; } 
>   list is simply executed in the current shell environment. 
>   list must   be terminated with a newline or semicolon.  This is known
>   as a group   command.  The return status is the exit status of list. 
>   Note that   unlike the metacharacters ( and ), { and } are reserved
>   words and   must occur where a reserved word is permitted to be
>   recognized.   Since they do not cause a word break, they must be
>   separated from   list by whitespace or another shell metacharacter.

So that would work as commands would not be executed in a subshell but
in a current shell environment:

```
{
var1="myvar1"
var2="myvar2";
}
```

I see you're asking a lot of simple questions about `Bash`. Consider
reading some Bash tutorials, `man bash` and learn about common [Bash
pitfalls](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls).

Comment: Some of the facts you mention I learned a few years back but some I forgot because I am not a professional sysadmin or doing sysadministration on a daily basis... Sometimes I prefer to ask to have direct documentation for me and others. I left my home country and left my books behind and not in a comfortable situation to read huge documentation. I had a Bash book from 2005 I used to read in train; I should buy the new edition in the right time for me...

Answer (score 1):

The parenthesis you used causes the enclosed commands to be executed by a subshell; hence once that shell exits, de variables are still not set in the current shell.

I'm at a loss why you think those parenthesis would set those variables "in one go", or why it would be necessary to them them "in one go"; however you could place those assignments on one line such as:

```
var1="myvar1" var2="myvar2"
```

Of course there's no reason not to copy and paste those lines all together in one paste, as Arkadiusz Drabczyk commented, if that's easier and all that you want to accomplish.